# Compute time difference for night shift time record

Tags: php, time

I am computing for the time difference of night shift schedule using time only

lets say that I have this data:

```
 $actual_in_time      = 6:45 PM        //date July 30, 2013
 $actual_out_timeout  = 7:00 AM        //date July 31, 2013
```

I have to compute for the time difference where the time in should be converted to a whole time, therefore

```
 $actual_in_time     = //(some code to convert 6:45 PM to 7:00 PM)
 $converted_in_time  = $actual_in_time;
```

Now here is my code to that:

```
 $actual_out_time   += 86400;
 $getInterval   = $actual_out_time - $converted_in_time;
 $hours     = round($getInterval/60/60, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
 $hours     = floor($hours);
```

I am not getting the results I wanted. How do you compute for the time difference where the basis is just the time?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://eval.in/39963). Not sure how will you handle the last case ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `DateTime` object

```
$start =  new DateTime('2000-01-01 6:45 PM');
$end =  new DateTime('2000-01-01 7:00 AM');
if ($end<$start)$end->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
$diff = date_diff($start,$end);
echo $diff->format('%h hours %i minutes');
```

Add 1 day if your end time is less than start time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second parameter in strtotime to get a relative time.

```
$start = strtotime($startTime);
$end = strtotime($endTime, $start);

echo ($end-$start)/3600;
```